# Why is my application not using its bootstrap classes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, bootstrap-4

Just beginning with Bootstrap and have had some success. However, bootstrap classes aren't rendering. What am I missing here?

```
<div class="position-absolute bottom-0 end-0 border border-dark">
```

[image]

However, using normal CSS styling works as expected.

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; border-style: solid;">
```

[image]
See full html code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <div id="background-div" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right: 10px;"> -->
        <div id="background-div" class="position-relative mx-10">
            <div id="title-div">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h3>One-liner goes here</h3>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div id="content-div" style="max-width: 66%;">
                <div class="row">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; border-style: solid;"> -->
            <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 end-0 border border-dark">
                <div id="legend-div">
                    legend goes here
                </div>
                <div id="scale-bar-div">
                    scalebar goes here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The CDN that I used was wrong. For reference, I was using the found on W3Schools ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)).

The working CDN to use is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I realise that this doesn't fix the bootstrap styling (as the classes do not produce the same result as the style attributes), but the main problem of bootstrap simply not working is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started with Bootstrap, it might be best to start with a current version. v5 is currently in Beta but appears to be quite stable and workable https://getbootstrap.com/

Note, in your answer you are still using an outdated BS, if you want to use v4 start here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/

There are a lot of bug fixes from 4.0 > 4.6

Comment: This is a good point - I hadn't thought of whether the version was current or not!

Answer (score 0):

While using Flask, if you are rendering HTML templates side by side (by running flask application) , you can try a hard refresh by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+R` (windows) because while using Flask changes in HTML or CSS don't take place immediately even after simple refresh!

OR

You try inspecting your HTML page in the developer's tool.
Opening developer's tool: `Ctrl+Shift+J` or `Right click<inspect page`
You can try seeing what CSS have been applied or not!

Comment: Thanks! This strategy definitely helped fix other issues I had with the app not rendering style changes